# casperjs: Phantomjs remains in process

Tags: memory-leaks, cron, phantomjs, casperjs

This is a picture of what `top` shows in my Ubuntu 14.04 server hosted in linode:

[image]

I have very limited knowledge about linux system or casperjs, so I will try to describe my usage of casperjs as precisely as possible.

Mine is a content website which publishes the owner's content that she previously posted on Youtube, v.qq.com and Blog.sina.com.cn. She wants the website to display "Hits" from those sites. So I use http://www.weiwei-tv.com/scrape/scrape.js to scrape video play times shown on youtube and v.qq.com, and http://www.weiwei-tv.com/scrape/scrape-sinaboke.js to scrape article hits from blog.sina.com.cn, then I save the data in a .json file so that my site can use them. Please be noted that because v.qq.com is in China and is pretty slow from my server, so I put a long wait time for the URLs from it in the script.

To keep the data updated, I create two different cron jobs for them respectively. The first .js runs every 30 mins, and the second every day at midnight. I think it worths mentioning that previously, I set the second cron jobs to run every hour, and the issue was much worse than what is shown in the picture above - I saw about ten phantomjs processes and each one of them is consuming 3~5% CPU.

[image]

First of all, I think this issue is probably because the casperjs script didn't properly exit(), am I right? 
That being said, there has been an issue with the first script: SOMETIMES, the script stops running when trying to scrape the video play times from v.qq.com (I haven't been able to figure out the reason, but it is probably related to how v.qq.com handles request), so is it possible that it didn't `exit` properly and remain alive?

Secondly, because there are lots of URLs to scrape in my first script, sometimes they can keep running for over 30 mins, meaning the next scheduled cron jobs starts running when the last one isn't finished yet. Does this create any problem and could it be the cause of the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a step time out by `var casper = require('casper').create({stepTimeout: 10000})`. If you have n steps, it will ends in `n*stepTimeOut` at most...